# Autologin to website using a link, by only accessing this link from Intranet

Tags: php, security, intranet

I have the following scenario.

We have a web site written in PHP, where a user needs to be logged-in in order to access the website.

Now different clients have login details, but we also need to provide a auto login feature where a link is given and stored on a page within the clients intranet, all employees working within this intranet should be able to auto login to the website using this link.

The problem however is, if this link is accessed outside the intranet the clients should not be able to auto login, but should use a username and password. Is there a way to check if the link was accessed within the Intranet of the client.

I thought about verifying the External IP address, but this could change if the ISP is using DHCP to assign IP Addresses.

Unfortunately the website can't be hosted within the intranet.

Comment: How would *all* employees be able to auto-login using a single link?

Comment: @arxanas - Though of giving the link a special string, which will verify the login

Comment: I mean to say, would they all have the same account? How would one link differentiate the employees?

Comment: @arxanas - Yes all would have the same account

Comment: Check out [NTLM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378749(v=vs.85).aspx) Authentication if you're on a windows network. It's true single-sign-on, and then have the rest of your authentication backed by active directory.

Comment: @ircmaxell - Yes they are all on Active Directory, so this should work

Answer (score 6):

Well this is *hacky*, but what you could do is that you have a cookie check in your PHP code for a certain cookie.

Let *everyone* in your office access a page that adds the cookie to their browser, then **restrict access to that page**.

Then allow people who have that cookie clearance to bypass the login within your PHP code.

Comment: This dos not solve problem, since person who is able to *steal* the autologin link can also steal the cookie. I wonder, who are the people who upvoted this stupid idea.

Comment: @tereško mmmmm ***coooookieees***